# App got rejected due to Guideline 5.2.5 - Legal - Intellectual Property

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

My iOS app has been rejected with the following error:

> Guideline 5.2.5 - Legal - Intellectual Property
>
> Your app does not comply with the Guidelines for Using Apple's Trademarks and Copyrights. Specifically, your app includes:
>
> - "My Application name" in the app name or subtitle in an inappropriate manner.
>
> Next Steps
>
> To resolve this issue, please revise your app and its metadata to address these trademark issues.

Comment: What is your app name?

Comment: This got nothing about programming. Go to https://law.stackexchange.com if you think your app complies with apple's trademarks and copyrights.

Comment: @mandeep what is your app name ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [questions about application stores are off-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/-) and [we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/-).

Answer (score 1):

From the apple [guideline](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/)

> 5.2.5 Apple Products: Don’t create an app that appears confusingly similar to an existing Apple product, interface (e.g. Finder), app
>   (such as the App Store, iTunes Store, or Messages) or advertising
>   theme. Apps and extensions, including third party keyboards and
>   Sticker packs, may not include Apple emoji. iTunes music previews may
>   not be used for their entertainment value (e.g. as the background
>   music to a photo collage or the soundtrack to a game) or in any other
>   unauthorized manner. If your app displays Activity rings, they should
>   not visualize Move, Exercise, or Stand data in a way that resembles
>   the Activity control. The Human Interface Guidelines have more
>   information on how to use Activity rings.

So there are few cases you may stuck on.

1. Your app name is already taken by any other app on app store.
2. Your app name is containing an apple emoji.

Answer (score 0):

As message from Apple says,

> Next Steps
>
> To resolve this issue, please revise your app and its metadata to address these trademark issues.

**Possible issue:**

1. Your app looks similar to an existing Apple product
2. Your app contains Apple emoji.

[Apple Guideline: 5.2 Intellectual Property](http://https:/https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#intellectual-property)

You need to change your app name or its functionality that uniquely identify your app on app store. Don't include apple emoji or any other confusing character in app name.